# Visual Studio 2010 to have larger viewing area for text editor

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Comparing VS2010 and VS2008, text editor area is smaller in VS2010. I have the default settings, which has below bars:

(These are on the top of text editor)

- function bar (file, edit, view, window, help, etc...)
- one row of toolbar (standard toolbar and text editor toolbar on the same row)
- opened file tab bar
- navigation bar

  (on the bottom of text editor)
- Tabs for docking hidden windows on the bottom (output window, error window, find result window, etc...)
- Status bar

VS2010 has larger bar height than VS2008, and makes the text editor display a couple line less (depending on the text font size). It's 3 lines less with Consolas font size 9.

Is there any way to make the VS2010 bars more compact? Since those bars are useful, I am trying not to disable any of them.

Comment: If you get to know your VS keyboard shortcuts (less need for toolbars) and keep your methods generally under 60 lines of code (best practice) then you won't be bothered by three fewer lines of display. You will also find yourself more productive and producing higher quality code.

Comment: I agree with Paul according shortcuts - this is really useful. Also you may try include in comparation VS 11 - according this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/02/23/introducing-the-new-developer-experience.aspx you will get 3 more extra lines b default